# Sublime Text 3 indentation for multi-line statements in PHP

Tags: php, sublimetext3, auto-indent

I'm having a little trouble with Sublime Text 3's autoindent (and reindent) for PHP. It doesn't seem to handle multi-line statements correctly. Consider the following code:

```
class Foo {
    function bar() {
        if (VeryLongThingThatTakesUpALotOfRoom ||
                OtherQuiteLongThingSoINeedTwoLines) {
            statement1();
            statement2();
        }
    }

    function baz() {
        whatever;
    }
}
```

Running `reindent` from the command palette results in

```
class Foo {
    function bar() {
        if (VeryLongThingThatTakesUpALotOfRoom ||
            OtherQuiteLongThingSoINeedTwoLines) {
            statement1();
        statement2();
    }
}

function baz() {
    whatever();
}
}
```

Not only is this incorrect indentation, it screws up the indentation for the remainder of the file, as it erroneously loses a level of indentation.

Less disastrously (but still annoyingly) the following code:

```
function foo() {
    return $thing->other_thing->really_quite_long_thing
        ->so_we_need_a_new_line_here();
}
```

`reindent`s to:

```
function foo() {
    return $thing->other_thing->really_quite_long_thing
    ->so_we_need_a_new_line_here();
}
```

How does one structure long (multi-line) statements such that Sublime Text 3 can correctly indent them?

Comment: seems this is a bug in the syntax definition. You can work around that behaviour for now by not using multi-line statements.